# Is there a task manager of sorts for SQL Server 2008 and on?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Is there a task manager of sorts for SQL Server 2008 and on?
A way to see what SQL server is doing, kill runaway queries, etc...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
select * 
from sys.sysprocesses
```

Should show you the processes running.    Kill tasks is the

```
KILL <task>
```

command

Note, this view (**`master.dbo.sysprocesses`**) is as a backward compatible view, so it might not be here in future SQL releases

Answer (score 6):

Activity Monitor: [How to: Open Activity Monitor (SQL Server Management Studio)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175518.aspx):

> Use Activity Monitor to obtain
>   information about SQL Server processes
>   and how these processes affect the
>   current instance of SQL Server.
>
> Activity Monitor is a tabbed document
>   window that has the following
>   expandable and collapsible panes:
>   Overview, Active User Tasks, Resource
>   Waits, Data File I/O, and Recent
>   Expensive Queries. When any pane is
>   expanded, Activity Monitor is querying
>   the instance for information. When a
>   pane is collapsed, all querying
>   activity stops for that pane. You can
>   also expand one or more panes at the
>   same time to view different kinds of
>   activity on the instance.
>
> For the columns that are included in
>   the Active User Tasks, Resource Waits,
>   Data File I/O, and Recent Expensive
>   Queries panes, you can customize the
>   display in the following ways:
>
> - To rearrange the order of the columns, click the column heading and
>     drag it to another location in the
>     heading ribbon.
> - To sort a column, click the column name.
> - To filter on one or more columns, click the drop-down arrow in
>     the column heading, and then select a
>     value.
>
> To view the Activity Monitor in SQL
>   Server 2005 and SQL Server 2008, a
>   user must have VIEW SERVER STATE
>   permission.
>
> To view the Activity Monitor on a SQL
>   Server 2000 server, a user must have
>   SELECT permission to the sysprocesses
>   and syslocks tables in the master
>   database. Permission to view these
>   tables is granted by default to the
>   public database role.
>
> To KILL a process, a user must be a
>   member of the sysadmin or processadmin
>   fixed server roles.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Management Studio and the activity monitor.

Answer (score 0):

I know the question is old, but I found it while looking for a solution to this problem.  After finding out some information, I figured I would leave it here for others.

Go to Server Manager->Diagnostics->Performance.  Double-click Performance and a sub-screen will appear with a blue hyperlink that reads 'Open Resource Monitor'.  This has much of the same functionality as Task Manager.