# How to Stop A ColdFusion MX-7 Scheduled Task that has already started

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-7

I inherited a coldfusion MX7 application that has a long running process, which the user kicked by accident.

By my calculations, at the current rate, the job will run for 3 days.

There doesnt seem to be a way through the administrator interface to stop a job that is running.

The table that is being filled can be easily repopulated, so I would think stopping the coldfusion service wont effect anything except the table, which isnt a problem.

Am I right? Is that safe? Is there another way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a one-time restart of the service should be fine. for the future, you may want to add a required url param or other such safety mechanism to keep this long process from accidentally going off.

Comment: Restarting the service could be disruptive.  Depending on what the scheduled job is doing, it might be better to let it run.  It's a judgement call.

Answer (score 1):

Check to see if the task already has an explicit timeout out set

- [Explicit Timeout](http://www.communitymx.com/content/source/46A29/)

Otherwise the default page time out is used

- [Server Settings](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Admin/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbf3638e6-7ffc.html#WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbf3638e6-7ffb)

For newer versions of ColdFusion 8 and above, you can kill a running page with with the Server Monitor in the section labeled "Aborting unresponsive or troublesome requests/threads"

- [Using server monitor](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/coldfusion/articles/monitoring_pt2.html).

It also may be possible to stop the processing by killing the SQL Server Task:

- [Is there a task manager of sorts for SQL Server 2008 and on?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3073248/is-there-a-task-manager-of-sorts-for-sql-server-2008-and-on)